# SSL certificates for 3rd party services over spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, ssl, emr

im trying to access a service (lets say mongodb) that requires SSL but the connection is rejected from the executor because i dont have the right SSL configurations set.

i know that when submitting a job, spark supports the following configuration:

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions
```

which then we can set the jvm ssl paths (and passwords respectively):

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
```

however, jvm requires those paths to be a physical path which results in a problem when using amazon's Spark EMR or any other spark cluster that doesnt give disc access, in which the required files can be pre deployed.

so basically my questions are:

1. is there a way for a spark job to push the truststore/keystore files to all executors ? --files can push the files to all executors but then i will have to get the absaloute path in each executor in order to set the correct config.
2. is there are away to run a job on all executors ? (in that job we can push the truststore/keystore from a neutral place to a tmp file on the executor context)
3. does jvm can be configured to handle a URI , i.e
   javax.net.ssl.trustStore=s3a://path/to/keystore.key ?

Answer (score 1):

Update : 
for AWS EMR solutions you can use the bootstrap action to launch script that copies from s3 into a predefined path on the server. each server that will be created under the EMR cluster will run this script individually.

unfortunately the way that YARN works is that spark job requests resources from YARN so running a spark job that copies a file from s3 and downloads it into a shared path 
(**note** : *Files.createTempFile(..)* wont work here because the tmp folder is overridden into the executor context folder)
will not guaranteed all nodes has this path. in addition once the job is finished the executor no longer has the JVM params that specifies the SSL configs , so once a new executor is created it no longer has the same JVM as the previous one.

another solution for this issue is to set this SSL params for every spark job that running  , but this code has to be inside the spark lib because it needs to be performed before any connections are made to the RDD source. for example mongo connector: once the application gets into the

```
val rdd = MongoSpark.load(..)
```

a connection is made to mongo which is already too late.

Comment: yes, use the EMR bootstrap action to retrive the cert files from s3 bucket on to the instance. edit the spark executor/driver cmd arg to point to the cert filea and also add the jvm and spark additional jvm properties to point to the certfile.

Comment: Hey Cal, thanks for the reply. This is the spark submit commad I'm using:--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/trustfile1.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password' --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/trustfile1.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password'  --class class app.jar

Comment: yeah exactly, I was also downloading the file into the machines using bootstrap actions. still I'm unable get it to work. this is the error I'm getting: 
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
 at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 0):

> does jvm can be configured to handle a URI , i.e
>   javax.net.ssl.trustStore=s3a://path/to/keystore.key ?

No, happens at a completely different IO level.

Generally pushing out something like this is done via cluster management tooling. You can get YARN's job submit API to copy out files too, but I don't know how well spark-submit is set up to let you add arbitrary files and then set JVM properties off them.

Of course, if it doesn't do that, and you do want it to, it's all OSS: you could add it and even (with tests), contributed it back

Answer (score 0):

This is same as making any other SSL connection. Import your cert in keystore and refer to that key store using below code

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keystoreFilefullpath")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password")
```

Once these params are set then Kafka SSL should work. If you are publishing from Spark then keystore file must be uploaded to driver/executor using **--files** option

--files options work for spark application running in cluster mode also